# How to show section respectively with each item in slide out menu using SWRevealController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller, side-menu

I have couple of sections in UITableView.
I make a slide-out menu with some items that are the names of sections in table.
How to show the section respectively with item tapped in menu.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your UITableView controller you need to reset the setFrontViewController for navigate relative controller after tapped item.

Comment: how to reset the setFrontViewController

Comment: The method setFrontViewController:animated: does no longer behave as previously. Particularly, it does not perform a full reveal animation. Instead it just replaces the frontViewController at its current position with optional animation. Use the new pushFrontViewController:animated: method as a replacement for your previous calls to setFrontViewController:animated:

Comment: if you still not able to get it let me know i will send you code as well.